# How to open Excel File in Browser using java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to open an Excel file in browser using java 1.6. If I have changed excel sheet cell value then it will reflect on original excel file...

How to do this?

Comment: This question is not clear. You want to open in browser meaning using a JSP/servlet? What does Java 1.6 have to do with it? How would you expect the changes made by client on the browser will affect the original file from the server?

Comment: i am using java 1.6 and apache poi 3.6 for excel manipulation.here, there is no client/server model.my Excel file residing on the server.the guy in server side can able to see that excel file in browser when clicking html submit button.And also allows him to make changes in the excel file and these changes will be changed back to excel sheet.how i do?

Comment: nope, still not clear. you say " there is no client/server model" and then you describe "the guy in server side sees the file in browser". i would like to help you, but your question is **just not making any sense** to me

Comment: My Application is a client - server Model.ok,come to the point.Excel file act like a configuration file,So Administrator on the server side wants to update some configuration information without opening the excel file manually.So, Whenever he hits the submit button,it shows the excel file in browser and allow the admin to make update it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the POI libary from Apache (http://poi.apache.org/) to create/manipulate .xls in the past quite successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I shall recommend to use JExcel API. I guess it is more convenient to use.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this post will help you to decide between POI and JExcel: http://java.itags.org/java-tools/122717/